# SVN: How to undo a reverse-merge?

Tags: svn, merge, undo, revert

I merged my checkout of the HEAD revision back to revision 1000:

```
$ svn merge -rHEAD:1000 .
--- Reverse-merging r2000 through r1001 into '.':
U    dir/foo.txt
```

After that, I'd like to undo that and merge back to HEAD revision. My checkout should be at revision 1000 now, so I need to merge everything from 1000 to HEAD. But svn doesn't do anything:

```
$ svn merge -r1000:HEAD .
```

Hmm, or just a revert?

```
$ svn revert .
```

It's just quiet and doesn't update `foo.txt` to the HEAD revision. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it recursivly,

```
svn revert -R .
```

Or revert only that changed file

```
svn revert dir/foo.txt
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! And does anyone know why `svn merge -r1000:HEAD .` didn't work?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but probably because svn recognizes that `HEAD` already was the last revision of the entity, which already went through all revisions between `REV` and `HEAD` (well, it's actually at `WORKING`, as you had local alterations), so it decided no alterations were required. It doesn't actually 'set back a revision', it applies the opposite diffs from those revisions, which is seen as a `new modification`. I checked: check out revision N & then do a `svn merge -rN:HEAD`, then it works (as in: it will apply all diffs, an update to `HEAD` results in conflicts even though theyŕe equal